# Android jellybean with Phonegap click not working

Tags: android, cordova, svg, onclick, android-4.3-jelly-bean

We are developing a Android Hybrid application using phonegap 3.2.2.

In one of the html page, we are rendering an 'svg' element with 'path' elements inside the svg. Each path element is bind to a click event using the jquery.

The issue we are facing is the "onclick event will not be triggered **only for some of the *path* elements and for rest it is working fine**" and also this we are getting only in the devices with Android OS 4.2 and 4.3 (All "Jelly Bean").

If anyone has faced the similar issue, kindly help.

HTML:

```
<div id="world-map" style="height: 634px;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="jvectormap-container"><svg width="600" height="634"><g transform="scale(1.3333333333333333) translate(-141.60559099033824, 17.39684462793349)"><path d="M652.71,228.85l-0.04,1.38l-0.46,-0.21l-0.42,0.3l0.05,0.65l-0.17,-1.37l-0.48,-1.26l-1.08,-1.6l-0.23,-0.13l-2.31,-0.11l-0.31,0.36l0.21,0.98l-0.6,1.11l-0.8,-0.4l-0.37,0.09l-0.23,0.3l-0.54,-0.21l-0.78,-0.19l-0.38,-2.04l-0.83,-1.89l0.4,-1.5l-0.16,-0.35l-1.24,-0.57l0.36,-0.62l1.5,-0.95l0.02,-0.49l-1.62,-1.26l0.64,-1.31l1.7,1.0l0.12,0.04l0.96,0.11l0.19,1.62l0.25,0.26l2.38,0.37l2.32,-0.04l1.06,0.33l-0.92,1.79l-0.97,0.13l-0.23,0.16l-0.77,1.51l0.05,0.35l1.37,1.37l0.5,-0.14l0.35,-1.46l0.24,-0.0l1.24,3.92Z" data-code="BD" fill="#B8E186" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/><path d="M429.28,143.95l1.76,0.25l0.13,-0.01l2.16,-0.64l1.46,1.34l1.26,0.71l-0.23,1.8l-0.44,0.08l-0.24,0.25l-0.2,1.36l-1.8,-1.22l-0.23,-0.05l-1.14,0.23l-1.62,-1.43l-1.15,-1.31l-0.21,-0.1l-0.95,-0.04l-0.21,-0.68l1.66,-0.54Z" data-code="BE" fill="#B8E186" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/><path d="M413.48,260.21l-1.22,-0.46l-0.13,-0.02l-1.17,0.1l-0.15,0.06l-0.73,0.53l-0.87,-0.41l-0.39,-0.75l-0.13,-0.13l-0.98,-0.48l-0.14,-1.2l0.63,-0.99l0.05,-0.18l-0.05,-0.73l1.9,-2.01l0.08,-0.14l0.35,-1.65l0.49,-0.44l1.05,0.3l0.21,-0.02l1.05,-0.52l0.13,-0.13l0.3,-0.58l1.87,-1.1l0.11,-0.1l0.43,-0.72l2.23,-1.01l1.21,-0.32l0.51,0.4l0.19,0.06l1.25,-0.01l-0.14,0.89l0.01,0.13l0.34,1.16l0.06,0.11l1.35,1.59l0.07,1.13l0.24,0.28l2.64,0.53l-0.05,1.39l-0.42,0.59l-1.11,0.21l-0.22,0.17l-0.46,0.99l-0.69,0.23l-2.12,-0.05l-1.14,-0.2l-0.19,0.03l-0.72,0.36l-1.07,-0.17l-4.35,0.12l-0.29,0.29l-0.06,1.44l0.25,1.45Z" data-code="BF" fill="#B8E186" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/><path d="M477.63,166.84l0.51,0.9l0.33,0.14l0.9,-0.21l1.91,0.47l3.68,0.16l0.17,-0.05l1.2,-0.75l2.78,-0.67l1.72,1.05l1.02,0.24l-0.97,0.97l-0.91,2.17l0.0,0.24l0.56,1.19l-1.58,-0.3l-0.16,0.01l-2.55,0.95l-0.2,0.28l-0.02,1.23l-1.92,0.24l-1.68,-0.99l-0.27,-0.02l-1.94,0.8l-1.52,-0.07l-0.15,-1.72l-0.12,-0.21l-0.99,-0.76l0.18,-0.18l0.02,-0.39l-0.17,-0.22l0.33,-0.75l0.91,-0.91l0.01,-0.42l-1.16,-1.25l-0.18,-0.89l0.24,-0.27Z" data-code="BG" fill="#B8E186" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/><path d="M468.39,164.66l0.16,0.04l0.43,-0.0l-0.43,0.93l0.06,0.34l1.08,1.06l-0.28,1.09l-0.5,0.13l-0.47,0.28l-0.86,0.74l-0.1,0.16l-0.28,1.29l-1.81,-0.94l-0.9,-1.22l-1.0,-0.73l-1.1,-1.1l-0.55,-0.96l-1.11,-1.3l0.3,-0.75l0.59,0.46l0.42,-0.04l0.46,-0.54l1.0,-0.06l2.11,0.5l1.72,-0.03l1.06,0.64Z" data-code="BA" fill="#B8E186" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/><path d="M707.34,273.57l0.76,-0.72l1.59,-1.03l-0.18,1.93l-0.9,-0.06l-0.28,0.14l-0.31,0.51l-0.68,-0.78Z" data-code="BN" fill="#B8E186" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"/></g><g/></svg><div class="jvectormap-zoomin">+</div><div class="jvectormap-zoomout">−</div></div></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#world-map').on('click','svg path', function (e) {


    var $this = $(e.target);
    alert($this.is('path'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove overflow attribute  from style ,this conflicts with click event in phonegap

Comment: ok,remove css attribute one by one to check which one is conflicting with click event,also use id name as world_map

Comment: Hi Gurtej, this svg we are creating using the javascript. Also, this functionality works fine in Android OS version 4.4 but it is giving the problem only in Jellybean OS.

Comment: This support in new versions of android but not in older one

Comment: yes, it works fine in new version (i.e. OS version 4.4).

Comment: when I tap the regions that are not working, it is logging as "Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found". I tried with all the solutions mentioned in the stackoverflow. But, still getting the same issue.I added the below code in the cordovawebview.   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            int temp_ScrollY = getScrollY();
            scrollTo(getScrollX(), getScrollY() + 1);
            scrollTo(getScrollX(), temp_ScrollY);

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

Comment: has anyone faced this kind of issue in Jellybean using webview?