# Can't click div in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Helo!

I am creating a cordova app, and run in to the following issue on S4 Mini, android 4.2.2.
I have a div element

```
<div class="switch" id="switchOff" onclick="clicked()">
  <img alt="switch off" src="img/70/switchOff.png" />
</div>
```

Theres no way I was able to react to a click event. I tried every possible way I know.

```
  $('#switchOff').css('position', 'relative');
  $('#switchOff').css('zIndex','10000');
  var foo = document.getElementById("switchOff");
  console.log('zindex: ' + $(foo).css('zIndex')); //gives it back, so it works
  $('#switchOff').bind('click',function(){
      alert('Bind is the winner');
  });

  foo.click = function(){
      alert('Native click is the winner');
  }

  $(document).on('click','#switchOff',function(){
            alert('Holaon');
  });

  document.getElementById("switchOff").addEventListener('click', function(){
      alert('eventlistener is a winner');
  }, false);
```

The most strange thing is that I can even change the attributes of that div, so the selector works, and its already loaded to the dom.
Another strange thing is that it works well on other devices. (motorola defy, xperia tablez-z, atrix).

I run out of ideas, can someone help with this?

Comment: try `.on` instead of `.bind`?

Comment: Yes, I missed it from the sample code, but already did that.

Comment: what happens if you move the click to the image?

Comment: apply click event on image.

Comment: Its not working on img either.

Comment: I found an issue that maybe has the same orgin.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470423/android-jellybean-with-phonegap-click-not-working

Comment: Can you upload only your relevant code to github or jsbin to better understand the issue?

Comment: @Nano There is no answear to my original question that I can accept. I mean I would be the happiest if we could find a sloution to my problem, but nothing relevant jet.

Comment: @SurajitSarkar I can't reproduce the error in JSBin in a simple example, since it should normally work because I don't know what causes the problem. I mean if I copy the above example to jsbin, it will work. The problem should be with the Cordova lib.

Answer (score 1):

where is your `clicked()` defined?
Did you wraped the whole code in the jquery ready listener like this?:

```
$(function(){
     $('#switchOff').click(function(){
         //do something
     });
});
```

Comment: Its defined above in the code.
Yes, I tried domready and deviceready as well(cordova suggested directiva).
But the script file is at the bottom of the page, so I'm not sure if that could be a problem on any elvel.

Comment: Its not a problem if it is under the jQuery lib

Comment: It is after that. And the click works well on galaxy s3, motorola defy, motorola atrix, sony z1, z1 mini, nexus 4, zte grand x in, z1 tablet....